# Couchbase spring data jpa to generate composite primary key

Tags: spring-boot, nosql, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Using Couchbase with Spring Data and JPA,
In my entity class How to create a Composite Key using two fields.
currently in Person class id is the primary key `@Id`
where I want combination of `id` and `name` will be primary key.

```
@Document
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String name;

    @Field
    private String city;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to achieve what you want using the following -

@Document

public class Person {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue()
String key;

@IdPrefix
String id;

@Field
@IdAttribute
String name;

@Field
private String city;
```

}

Use `@IdSuffix` if you want the value in id to be after the name . When constructing the above object don't assign a value to key variable yourself as the value doesn't get autogenerated if you provide one of your own as per docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.autokeygeneration.configuration .